# slanger / pusher in ubuntu: connecting -> unavailable

Tags: javascript, connection, pusher

I use slanger with pusher on my ubuntu server. For me and the most of my user it works perfectly but some user can't connect to the server. They got this error in console:

```
Pusher : State changed : connecting -> unavailable
```

So i thought it was an general issue of them, but they can get connection at test-site of pusher (http://test.pusher.com/). So i hope you can help me to get the right solution.

This is my Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Pusher.log = function(data) {
        //console.log('\t\t', data);
    };

    var pusher = new Pusher('a924746cc269f156596205d5cdab7861', {
        wsHost: "web-lst.de",
        wsPort: "8080",
        enabledTransports: ['ws', 'flash']
      });

    pusher.connection.bind('unavailable', function() {
        console.log('webNET nicht erreichbar!');
    }); 

    pusher.connection.bind('connected', function() {
        console.log('webNET verbunden!');
        var global_message = pusher.subscribe('global_message');

        global_message.bind('message_event', function(data) {
            toastr.options.timeOut = 0;
            switch(data['type']){
                case 'info':
                    toastr.info(data['body'], data['header']);
                    break;
                case 'success':
                    toastr.info(data['body'], data['header']);
                    break;
                case 'warning':
                    toastr.info(data['body'], data['header']);
                    break;
                case 'error':
                    toastr.info(data['body'], data['header']);
                    break;
                default:
                    toastr.info(data['body'], data['header']);
            }
        });
    });     
</script>
```

Comment: What information do you get when you log the debug information from the Pusher JavaScript library? https://pusher.com/docs/debugging#pusher_logging

Comment: Good news, it wasn't a problem by myself. The user with the problem has been following the program avast antivirus, which for whatever reason blocks the connection to us.